# Access issue while accessing calender data using MS Azure

Tags: azure-active-directory

```
"Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Scope": ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"],
"InstanceURL": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
API  - > /users/{}/calendarView with start and end query
```

will application permissions along with calendar Read all, But still receiving below error
{"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."}}

Comment: Are you using client credentials grant type?

Comment: Check the access token if possible at e.g. https://jwt.ms. It should contain `"roles": ["Calendars.Read.All"]` or something similar if permissions are there.

Comment: These are scopes in token roles:                                                                                          [ "User.ReadBasic.All", "Calendars.Read", "Mail.ReadBasic.All", "User.Read.All", "Calendars.ReadBasic.All", "Mail.Read", "Calendars.ReadWrite", "Mail.ReadBasic" ]            
 , Also got granted for admin consent

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:**

I registered one Azure AD application and added  `Calendars.Read`  permission like below:

[image]

Now I generated  *access token*  using  **client credentials**  flow via Postman like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
scope: https://grsph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used the above token to get calendar views, I got  **same error**  as below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/username@xxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/calendarView?startDateTime=2022-01-01T19:00:00-08:00&endDateTime=2022-01-02T19:00:00-08:00
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to grant  **admin consent**  to below permissions:

[image]

After granting the admin consent, I generated the token again and got the  **calendar views**  successfully like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/username@xxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/calendarView?startDateTime=2022-01-01T19:00:00-08:00&endDateTime=2022-01-02T19:00:00-08:00
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: These are scopes in token  roles:                                                                                                     [

  "User.ReadBasic.All",

  "Calendars.Read",

  "Mail.ReadBasic.All",

  "User.Read.All",

  "Calendars.ReadBasic.All",

  "Mail.Read",

  "Calendars.ReadWrite",

  "Mail.ReadBasic"

 ],                                                                                                                                                     Also got granted  for admin consent

Comment: For fetching calander information "Calendars.Read" Scope is enough, if you want to fetch other information use other scopes.